# Split single column JSON in numpy into multiple column array

Tags: python, json, numpy

I am using Elastic Search and after a query, I get a result. With Pandas, I am able to split the resulting JSON into columns, thus I can perform any operation on any single column.

I want to do same with numpy. But if I do with numpy, I am only able to achieve a single column JSON.

```
data = np.array(result_dict['aggregations']['date']['buckets'])


array([{u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 1547577000000, u'doc_count': 1},
       {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 1547663400000, u'doc_count': 3},
       {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 1547749800000, u'doc_count': 3},
       {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 1547836200000, u'doc_count': 3}],
      dtype=object)
```

The problem is that in this case if I have to access doc_count values, I have to write one more line of code. Knowing numpy is pretty fast, if there is a way to do 3 column split of this JSON by numpy itself at the time of initialization of array, it would be much faster for large set of data.

So that I can access data say by column like:

```
data[:, 'doc_count']
```

Making it easy to access individual columns.

Please note, I want to avoid python loop to do this. Have already done with Pandas. I want to know if numpy can do it by its own internal functions.

Comment: The fast numpy methods work with numbers. You have an object dtype array containing dictionaries. Working with a list of those dictionaries will be faster.

Comment: @hpaulj actually my interest is in the column 'doc_count' only, which is a number, so if there is a way to extract just that column in the beginning itself into numpy array, am okay with that also

Comment: Sure iterate on the dictionaries. pandas can make a dataframe  from dictionaries. numpy does not have any specialized dictionary handling.

Comment: @hpaulj I already did with Pandas. With iteration, yes I did. I wanted to do without all that in numpy. Anyway, if there is no way, then I would use pandas

Answer (score 0):

you have to manipulate your data to get a matrix representation of your table/json, you could try:

```
import numpy as np


r = np.array([{'key_as_string': '2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', 'key': 1547577000000, 'doc_count': 1},
       {'key_as_string': '2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', 'key': 1547663400000, 'doc_count': 3},
       {'key_as_string': '2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', 'key': 1547749800000, 'doc_count': 3},
       {'key_as_string': '2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', 'key': 1547836200000, 'doc_count': 3}],
      dtype=object)

header = r[0].keys()
rows = np.append([list(header)],  [[e[h] for h in header] for e in  r] , axis=0)

print(rows)
# array([['key_as_string', 'key', 'doc_count'],
#        ['2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547577000000', '1'],
#        ['2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547663400000', '3'],
#        ['2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547749800000', '3'],
#        ['2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547836200000', '3']],
#       dtype='<U29')

rows[:, 2]
# array(['doc_count', '1', '3', '3', '3'], dtype='<U29')
```

if you do not want to include the header in the columns:

```
header = list(r[0].keys())
rows = np.array([[e[h] for h in header] for e in  r])

print(rows)
#array([['2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547577000000', '1'],
#       ['2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547663400000', '3'],
#       ['2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547749800000', '3'],
#       ['2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', '1547836200000', '3']],
#     dtype='<U29')
rows[:, header.index('doc_count')]
# array(['1', '3', '3', '3'], dtype='<U29')
```

Comment: but this is looping. I already said without loop. If there is no way without looping then maybe the right answer is that there is no solution

Comment: i guess you want all the job to be  done from library api, I'm sure that Pandas is doing the trick also with "looping", you could just make a custom function to do it or if you do not really need to work with numpy is just fine to use Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

While pandas can make a dataframe from a list with a simple call, that doesn't mean it is fast.

```
In [260]: alist =[{u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 1
     ...: 547577000000, u'doc_count': 1},
     ...:        {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 15
     ...: 47663400000, u'doc_count': 3},
     ...:        {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 15
     ...: 47749800000, u'doc_count': 3},
     ...:        {u'key_as_string': u'2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', u'key': 15
     ...: 47836200000, u'doc_count': 3}]
     ...:        
In [261]: pd.DataFrame(alist)
Out[261]: 
   doc_count              ...                                key_as_string
0          1              ...                2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30
1          3              ...                2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30
2          3              ...                2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30
3          3              ...                2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30

[4 rows x 3 columns]
In [262]: _.dtypes
Out[262]: 
doc_count         int64
key               int64
key_as_string    object
dtype: object
In [263]: timeit pd.DataFrame(alist)
694 µs ± 19.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In my comments I was focused on accessing the dictionaries key by key, but forgot that we can quickly access all values as a list.

```
In [264]: [tuple(d.values()) for d in alist]
Out[264]: 
[('2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547577000000, 1),
 ('2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547663400000, 3),
 ('2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547749800000, 3),
 ('2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547836200000, 3)]
In [265]: timeit [tuple(d.values()) for d in alist]
1.43 µs ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Compared to `pandas` that's blazingly fast.

I used `tuple` so this list could be passed to a structured array:

```
In [266]: dt = np.dtype([('key_as_string', 'U40'),('doc_count', int),('id',int)]
     ...: )
In [267]: np.array([tuple(d.values()) for d in alist],dt)
Out[267]: 
array([('2019-01-16T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547577000000, 1),
       ('2019-01-17T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547663400000, 3),
       ('2019-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547749800000, 3),
       ('2019-01-19T00:00:00.000+05:30', 1547836200000, 3)],
      dtype=[('key_as_string', '<U40'), ('doc_count', '<i8'), ('id', '<i8')])
In [268]: timeit np.array([tuple(d.values()) for d in alist],dt)
5.12 µs ± 34.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Or to convert the strings to datetimes

```
In [269]: dt1 = np.dtype([('key_as_string', 'datetime64[m]'),('doc_count', int),
     ...: ('id',int)])
In [270]: np.array([tuple(d.values()) for d in alist],dt1)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated; this will raise an error in the future
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[270]: 
array([('2019-01-15T18:30', 1547577000000, 1),
       ('2019-01-16T18:30', 1547663400000, 3),
       ('2019-01-17T18:30', 1547749800000, 3),
       ('2019-01-18T18:30', 1547836200000, 3)],
      dtype=[('key_as_string', '<M8[m]'), ('doc_count', '<i8'), ('id', '<i8')])
```

That's a little slower, but still much faster the pandas.

And to access just one key across the dictionaries:

```
In [273]: [d['doc_count'] for d in alist]
Out[273]: [1, 3, 3, 3]
In [274]: np.array([d['doc_count'] for d in alist])
Out[274]: array([1, 3, 3, 3])
In [275]: timeit np.array([d['doc_count'] for d in alist])
2.69 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And lets test a bigger list:

```
In [308]: blist = alist * 1000
In [309]: timeit np.array([d['doc_count'] for d in blist])
430 µs ± 67.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [310]: timeit np.array([tuple(d.values()) for d in blist],dt)
2.18 ms ± 4.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [311]: timeit pd.DataFrame(blist)
5.6 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Pandas doesn't look so bad!